# .htaccess DirectoryIndex not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website running on Linux/UNIX but I don’t know a darn thing about the .htaccess file and the syntax used in it..

If you go to `http://pr.bananapages.net` the system won’t produce any results.
But if you add the file name, it comes up. ex: `http://pr.bananapages.net/index.html`

**NOTE:** The URL points to a subfolder on the shared access hosting server but it doen't really matter because when you type in `www.bananapages.net/pr/hamshack`, (That's where the short cut DNS address points to), It still won't produce the index.html file without actually specifying it.

I have tried everything I could find about `DirectoryIndex` but I can’t get it to work without using the file name… (index.html)

This is my current `.htccess` file.

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex system.php index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex system.php index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Google sitemap controller
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ tmp/sitemap.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^tmp/sitemap.xml$ tmp/sitemap.xml [L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.xml|\.php([0-9]*)|\.tpl|\.phtml|\.ini|\.inc|/)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

# compresses text, html, javascript, css and xml
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

**NOTE:** If I rename the `.htaccess` file, it will work without specifying the filename, (index.html) so. I am fairly certain there is something in this `.htaccess` file preventing this from working the desired way.

Comment: Firstly, remove all code other than `DirectoryIndex system.php index.html`, then try. if it works, then the code is localized somewhere else. if it doesn't work, then your system.php has invalid code and therefore is the cause of the 500 ISE. Check your servers error logs for hints.

Comment: Hey... Thanks guys for all your input... Maybe you can help me figure out what version of the OS I have and where the other two files might reside... I am in a shared hosting environment so I don't have access to anything other than the htdocs root folder in my hosting package...

Comment: @user2975488 is mod_rewrite loaded?

Comment: Just so you know, I did one thing your folks recommended... I deleted everything after DirectoryIndex system.php index.html and it worked, so something below that line is causing it to fail... AND:  How can I tell if mod_rewrite is loaded?  Please advise....

Comment: @user2975488 Remove the `<IfModule>` and `</IfModule>` lines, and if it doesn't return a 500 error, it's loaded

Comment: I removed those lines and it did not throw any errors so I guess as you said, it is loaded.  However, removing those lines did not solve the issue.  I still need to specify the index.html file name. Of course, I put the contents back into the file after testing it everything below the DirectoryIndex system.php index.html removed.  Any other suggestions?  Please advise....

Comment: Removing those lines wasn't supposed to fix the issue, it simply changes where the problem could be. You have a `DirectoryIndex` **inside** an `<IfModule>` container, so if the module isn't loaded, then that second `DirectoryIndex` is ignored.

Comment: oK, I used the idea of commenting out a line at a time and I figured out which line is causing the issue...  The line that says: 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L] 
is causing the issue.  If I remove that line, (comment it out) the index.html file will load when I use pr.bananapages.net but the home page at www.bananapages.net comes up screwed.  When I put the line back in, it won't load the index.html file anymore on the folder.  So can anyone tell me how to get the best of both worlds?  What is the solution? Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

in all your

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

Double it as thus, to say to do rewrite only if lt's neither directory, nor file:

#### Edit

(Tested in Debian/Apache2).

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex system.php index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Google sitemap controller
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ tmp/sitemap.xml [L]
#RewriteRule ^tmp/sitemap.xml$ tmp/sitemap.xml [L]
#RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.xml|\.php([0-9]*)|\.tpl|\.phtml|\.ini|\.inc|/)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to see if it works better? Please notice some commented infinite loop rewriterule.

Comment: Ok jacouh: I tried your idea but it causes the home page to fail. I get: Error, Requested URL not found (404) on the home page, but the URL of pr.bananapages.net Does come up. I need to have both of them come up.  Did you read my comment about the line that has: 

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L] 

in it? I isolated the line causing the error. Please read my comments.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add !-d Only here: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: Jacouh:  That's exactly what I did previously and I told you about the results.  The problem child is in this line:  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ system.php?_p=$1 [QSA,L] -->  Thanks for your continued effort and support. I guess we have to hope others are also reading this thread..  Dale

Comment: You might not test it, have you noticed this line in error: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f <= RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

Comment: I'm afraid I am missing what you are trying to tell me...  Do you mean that there is a line with the wrong syntax?  Please point it our to me because I don't see it if there is one...  Please advise...

Comment: I just copied your code and overwrote my current .htaccess file (I made a good backup) and I got this message on the home page...  Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Sorry, this may be an infinite loop. We shall wait for another author. But it works in my server?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on my vps

I wanted my default homepage to be login.php so if someone where to go to http://[ip]/[folder]/ it would just load the login.php file that I set in my .htaccess within the [folder]

so i set 'DirectoryIndex login.php' in .htaccess but

it would not work instead I would get a 403 when going to http://[ip]/[folder]/ as I didn't have any index.html or index.php

so...

I decided to check the apache config file httpd.conf and under DirectoryIndex I put 'login.php' as part of the list that was already there then restarted the httpd service and

it worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

Here's the answer...

```
# Rules for subfolders
# for pr.bananapages.net
RewriteRule ^pr/(.*)$ pr/$1 [L]
# for jm.bananapages.net    
      RewriteRule ^jm/(.*)$ jm/$1 [L]
# and so on....
      RewriteRule ^dr/(.*)$ dr/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^usvi/(.*)$ usvi/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^bvi/(.*)$ bvi/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^kitts/(.*)$ kitts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ar/(.*)$ ar/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tt/(.*)$ tt/$1 [L]
```

I don't know why that works but it does seem to work...
Dale